# Navigating with Android Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

i am creating a diary application that has a page for showing: diary entries, new diary entries and events that the user has coming up, my application will use a database to store entries and display.

I was wondering how best to go about navigation in my app, as i wanted to use a navigation drawer. Can navigation drawer's be used to navigate between activities and if not how would i implement fragments to be handle the functionality i want?

Answer (score 0):

A `NavigationDrawer` is typically used to navigate between a few Fragments. A main `Activity` is used to handle user interaction with the `NavigationDrawer` and will typically attach the corresponding `Fragment` to a container within the `Activity`.

With that being said, your best bet would be following the full tutorial posted on the [Android developers](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) webpage. The tutorial contains each step necessary to successfully implement a `NavigationDrawer` in your application. In addition, you may download the completed and functional project from that tutorial and import it into your IDE.

Good luck and happy coding!